# Replace a string in JavaScript and PHP

Tags: php, javascript

How can I replace this character `|` in JavaScript?

```
<html>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

var str="data|data|data";
document.write(str.replace(/|/g,"<br />"));

</script>
```

In the output of given code, every character has the "< br />"

I don't know what is wrong with my code.. :)

Also, for PHP, I want the function to use if the input is

```
|string||
```

and the output should be

```
string
```

only. I want only the outer part of the string in PHP to be subtituted: `||hel||lo||` would become `hel||lo`.

Could I use `trim()`? I think `trim()` only applies to white spaces.

Comment: You chould post 2 separate questions (especially in different languages) as, well, 2 seperate questions.

Comment: Seconded - from your comments below, the PHP question seems to be slightly different from the JS one, but that was not obvious from the question. I'd say those two are different enough for posting as two different questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**JavaScript:**

You have to escape the pipe symbol:

```
document.write(str.replace(/\|/g,"<br />"));
//                       ---^
```

---

**PHP:**

You can pass another parameter to [`trim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) that specifies which characters to remove:

```
$str = trim($str, '| ');
```

If you also want to remove the character in the middle of the string you can use [`str_replace()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
$str = str_replace('|', '', $str);
```

Answer (score 4):

<strike>You don't need a regular expression for this - if you pass a string as the first argument to `replace()`, it will be replaced literally:</strike>

```
var str='data|data|data';
str = str.replace('|', '');
```

...but it will only replace the first match. For a global replace, you need to specify the `global` flag:

```
var str='data|data|data';
var re = new RegExp('\|','g'); // G is the 'global' flag
str = str.replace(re,'');
```

In PHP, [str_replace()](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) works with string literals:

```
$str='data|data|data';
$str = str_replace('|', '', $str);
// $str == datadatadata
```

If you only want to remove the outer delimiters, use [trim()](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php):

```
$str='|||data|data||data|';
$str = trim($str,'|');
// $str == 'data|data||data';
```

Comment: That is not correct. In JavaScript, it will only replace the first occurrence of `|`, you *have* to use regular expressions here.

Comment: i want only the outer part of the string in php to be subtituted.. like "||hel||lo||" and the output would be "hel||lo"

Comment: @vrynxzent: You can use `trim()` for this, see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

you need to escape the | character because it is used as OR in regex /a|b/ matches either a OR b.
Try /\|/

Edit:
To achieve wour last goal try doing it this way (alot of regex,I know):

```
document.write(str.replace(/(\|)+$/g,"").replace(/^(\|)+/g,"").replace(/(\|)+/g,"<br />"));
```

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript, you'll need to escape that pipe character:

```
alert("data|data|data".replace(/\|/g,"<br />"))
```